# Changing a Macro variable character value

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following macro variable:

```
%LET TEST= A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;
```

My original goal is to add a prefix to each of the characters where we have:

TEST1 = LG_A1 LG_A2 LG_A3 LG_A4 LG_A5

I tried to do this using the tranwrd function through the following way:

```
%Let TEST1= %SYSFUNC(TRANWRD(&TEST, "A", "LG_A"));
```

or

```
%Let TEST1= %SYSFUNC(TRANWRD(&TEST, A, LG_A));
```

But couldn't get the result either way.

Is there a way using other methods or the tranwrd function to get the required results?

Comment: Your second attempt without quotes works fine for me, you have a different error elsewhere.

Comment: It is handy to do with regular expression.  %let test1=%sysfunc(prxchange(s/(\w{2})/LG_$1/,-1,&test));

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to loop through all the words and add a prefix to each of them.

```
%LET TEST= A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;

%macro add_prefix();
    %global TEST1;
    %let TEST1 =;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&TEST));
        %let TEST1 = &TEST1 LG_%scan(&test,&i);
    %end;
%mend;
%add_prefix();
%put &TEST1;
```

Just noticed that you can also just remove the " signs to get the same results. But since you've already tried that without the proper results I'm at a  loss.

```
%Let TEST1= %sysfunc(TRANWRD(&TEST, A, LG_A));
```